# Rails Where Created_at Equals specific number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to figure out how to do a query where `created_at.year` == a given year, and `created_at.month` equals a given month.

However I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

`Model.where("'created_at.month' = ? AND 'created_at.year' = ?", 7,2013)`

results in nothing being shown.

However when I try `Model.first.created_at.month ==7` and 
`Model.first.created_at.year ==2013` I get true for both.

Therefore theoretically my query should be at least be returning my first record.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong or any alternative way to find records created on specific months?

Note that in my views the month / year will be parameters but for the purposes of this example I used actual values.

using ruby 1.9.3
rails 3.2.13

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`created_at` is a timestamp; it is not a set of discrete fields in the database. `created_at.year` and such don't exist in your DB; it's simply a single timestamp field. When you call `@model.created_at.year`, Rails is loading the `created_at` field from the database, and creating a Time object from it, which has a `#year` method you can call.

What you want is to query on a range of dates:

```
Model.where("created_at >= ? and created_at < ?", Time.mktime(2013, 7), Time.mktime(2013, 8))
```

This will find any Model with a created_at timestamp in July 2013.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `extract` SQL function, that will extract the month and year of the timestamp:

```
Model.where('extract(year from created_at) = ? and extract(month from created_at) = ?', '2013','7')
```

This query should give you the desired result.